# Are there any fundamental differences to use numpy.zeros or zeros?

Tags: python, numpy

I have downloaded the python 2.6 and installed `numpy-1.6.1-win32-superpack-python2.6` and `scipy-0.9.0-win32-superpack-python2.6`.  It is running on a Window with window 2000 professional as OS.

However, when I run python, with the following commands, following error message appear, could you mind to teach me how to solve it?

```
>>> x = zeros([K], int32)

Traceback (most recent call last):
file "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'zeros' is not defined.
```

I then tried to import `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> x=numpy.zeros([K], int32)
Traceback (most recent call last):
file "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'K' is not defined.
```

Are there any fundamental differences to use `numpy.zeros` or `zeros`?  What is the difference between them?

I also tried to readin a series of files (saved in the same directory) to get python doing analysis for me.  I learnt from the manual that I should use

```
f=open('C:/xxx.txt', 'w') # for single file
```

How to apply this to a series of files?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. You asked two. Have a read of the [faq].

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it all: You're using a name that hasn't been defined yet.

If you `import numpy`, and `numpy` contains a `zeros()` function, then you must call it as `numpy.zeros()`. If you want to refer to `zeros()` directly, you can `from numpy import zeros`.

If you pass the variable `K` to a function, `K` must have been assigned to something before. What is `K` supposed to be in your example?

As for opening files, I don't think the manual says that. At least, it should be `f = open(r'C:\xxx.txt', 'w')`.

To open more than one in a loop, you can

```
for filename in filelist:
    with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
        # do something.
        # The with block ensures that the file will be closed after use
```

Also check out the [`glob` module](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) and [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk).

All this is covered pretty well in the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

Your problem is not with `numpy`, it is simply that you have not defined `K`.

**Question 2**

One simple way to enumerate files in a directory is `glob`.

```
from glob import glob
for filename in glob('*.txt'):
    print filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/tutorial/index.html) to get your answers. The first code sample doesn't work because you didn't import `zeros`. The second - because you don't have `K` variable.